# Create a method to set attributes after initializing an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm initializing a new object and setting the attributes (because there are no attributes for this particular object) before rendering a form like so:

```
def new
  Book.new title: nil, author: nil, genre: nil, language: nil, ect...
end
```

This to me looks like a code smell.

I'm trying to set the attributes in a method within the model so I can increase readability by using: `Book.new.set_attributes`. So my `set_attributes` method in the Book model would look like:

```
def set_attributes
  {posted: nil, company: nil, poster: nil, city: nil, state: nil, title: nil, body: nil, keywords: nil}
end
```

However this does not work (with or without the `{}` brackets). Is it possible to call a method after using `.new`?

Comment: Did you get to a good place with this?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's constructor method is `initialize`, not `new`. You shouldn't try to define a method called `new`. Do something like:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author
  def initialize(title = nil, author = nil)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize nil values. When calling Book.new, any values that are not provided in a hash (e.g., Book.new(title: 'Bozo', author: 'Clown')) will be nil automatically.